# How to open and append data into excel using javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, excel, wsh

I would like to know how to append html input data into Excel using JavaScript.

I have written code for creating excel using JavaScript with `ActiveXObject` please find below sample written code :

```
<head>
  <script language="javascript">
    function WriteToFile(passForm) {
       var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
       var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
       ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = passForm.FirstName.value;
       ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,2).Value = passForm.LastName.value;
       ExcelSheet.SaveAs("D:\\TEST.xlsx");
       ExcelSheet.Application.Quit();
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body">
  <p>create a excel file with following details -</p>
<form>
   Type your first name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20">
   Type your last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="20">
   <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="WriteToFile(this.form)">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following task we need to do :

1. Open existing excel if not exist then create new excel and open
2. Fill the data into excel from HTML form

All above task need to do with the help of JavaScript.

Comment: You can't expect every user has Excel installed. ActiveXs work only in IEs and accessing users filesystem via web should not be possible. Your best bet would be to do this on server-side.

Comment: Yeah that is true but I have to use internet explorer only at least help me for how to append data into excel using JavaScript. Your help would be appreciated sir. I want to do only save and append html user input data into excel using JavaScript